# AR Text Recognition

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning, augmented-reality, vuforia

How do I integrate text recognition in my AR Application since Vuforia’s text recognition is deprecated? Are there any other ways?

Is there any way to use APIs or OpenCV with Vuforia and how to do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's [MLKit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit) that does on-device text recognition really well on both Android and iOS.

Google does not currently provide a Unity plugin, so you have to either write your own wrapper for both Android and iOS or buy [Easy ML Kit](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/easy-ml-kit-220512) from the asset store (I have not tried this)

If you go the build-your-own-wrapper-way, a fairly easy approach is to save a screenshot to Application.persistentData and built native plugins that loads the screenshot into the OCR-module and returns the results. If you limit the text scanning to a smaller region of the screen this approach can run realtime on most devices.

MLKit does not track text in 3D. If that is something you need, you'll have to either calculate that using the camera position and text bounding box over time, or raycast to detected planes.